# Create aliases for Vagrant virtual machines

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, aliases

I am on Ubuntu 14.10 64.x.
Using Vagrant, Virtualbox I can see all the **boxes** with the vagrant command

```
vagrant box list
```

An example output may be this:

```
geerlingguy/ubuntu1404         (virtualbox, 1.0.4)
hashicorp/precise64            (virtualbox, 1.1.0)
panamax-coreos-box-647.2.0     (virtualbox, 0)
precise-vbox-4.2.18.2          (virtualbox, 0)
precise32                      (virtualbox, 0)
precise64current               (virtualbox, 0)
ubuntu-precise12042-x64-vbox43 (virtualbox, 0)
ubuntu/trusty64                (virtualbox, 0.10)
```

As you can see some boxes may be **duplicates** or almost the same. Any time a Vagrantfile needs a box which name does not exist in the system vagrant starts downloading it.

I would like to be able to create **aliases** for each box in order Vagrant can find them on the system. For example this box

```
ubuntu/trusty64
```

may have these aliases set by me of course:

```
ubuntu/trusty64
trusty64
ubuntu/14.04
```

So I am asking. Is there any vagrant plugin or script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you can't be sure they're exactly the same, almost always boxes will have post provisioning process before they're created which add's the main user account, configures default settings and install provisioners etc.

Therefore, although they might all be based on ubuntu 14.04 they are likely all configured differently and not compatible with other provisioners.

Comment: This may be true but I do have duplicates and I know that. Also, when a project does not need something special there is no need to download another one. This list is an example.

Comment: If you're 100% sure the project doesn't require a custom base box then they should then reference a common base box -- eg. https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64